# Why does SE misspell "occurred" as "occured"?

Tags: bug, status-completed

To see examples of the misspelling, visit this link:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/55665/revisions

On the right hand side, you should see the word, e.g. "occured Dec 13 '20 at 1:05" at the top of the column.

*Can this be fixed?*

(note, this also occurrs elsewhere: [Typo in "An error occured when uploading the image". occured -> occurred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364538/typo-in-an-error-occured-when-uploading-the-image-occured-occurred))

Comment: Probably best to see if someone has reported it on MSE (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364538/typo-in-an-error-occured-when-uploading-the-image-occured-occurred seems to be a separate instance of the same word), and if not then to report it there. As for "why", probably because people make mistakes.

Comment: Added the status-review tag which should bring this to the attention of SE staff in [about 6 to 8 units](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514). Likely to be low-priority but also an easy fix; will probably get done in a broader sweep taking care of this sort of thing.

Comment: @BryanKrause Why was the other typo on purpose (as per your edit)? Is there some context to that post that I am missing?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Sorry, just a dumb joke I made that isn't landing; I intentionally incorrectly put an extra 'r' in "occurrs/occurs" in that edit since I happened to be using the word at issue to describe another post.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ohh, I get it now, thanks! I had thought that you meant that the typo reported in the linked post was on purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> misspelling

Agree that this is a misspelling. I expected it was a valid alternate spelling in some corner of the Anglophone world, but it appears to be a simple error.

> Can this be fixed?

Not by Academia.SE mods. This seems to be a site-wide issue, and if there is any client-side control over this text, it is not something we have access to either. As Bryan said in the comments, the next step would be to make the request on Meta.SE, if it hasn't already been requested (but these types of bugs tend to be considered low priority).

Comment: Maybe: 1) inform the big Meta staff to search every occurrence  of this spelling-wrong word and remedy them? 2) Somehow migrate this from here to Meta.SE?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy I asked for guidance on what mods should do when this sort of question is asked on a site meta even though it applies to the whole SE, and the answer was to status-review tag it as I have done which will automatically add it to a queue for review by SE staff. They're aware of this spelling error in a couple places and will look for others as well when they get around to fixing it. I don't know who the "big Meta staff" are you're talking about but this is not the responsibility of MSE mods and there isn't any other "Meta staff".

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes I meant the normal staff by "big Meta staff" I used the word *big* because, er, Meta.SE is big. I didn't know the status-review tag point the questions to a specific queue.

Comment: @BryanKrause something off-topic: a good portion of status-review tagged posts, haven't got attention in 5 years in the Meta.SE (some even has no response ! let alone the status-review tag). Let's see how this get handled.

Comment: @VScode_fanboy There have been some efforts to address the backlog like https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361140/ticket-smash-for-status-review-tag , but overall this status-review tag=in the queue procedure is relatively new: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca so I don't know that the older posts are really a good way to judge.

Comment: If the question doesn't even have status-review, then it hasn't been put in the queue and it's ordinarily up to the mods to do so (you can flag for moderator attention if you have a MSE post that you think should be reviewed after reading that MSE post about status-review). My impression is that SE has made a strong effort to respond to these more recently, after going through a period in which feedback from meta was perhaps...undervalued. This has been part of stated efforts by the CEO, CPO/CTO, and VP of community to value and prioritize input from SE users.

Comment: @BryanKrause I didn't know about that effort. I already read the second question you linked.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for the report!  This has been fixed sitewide, along with another 21 other "*occurrences*" of the same misspelling.

Interestingly, this is one of [*the 100 most common misspellings*](https://www.englishclub.com/spelling/misspellings.htm) and not a single person in my house could spell it either.